# How to avoid mentioning file names in an import statement in Python?

Tags: python, setuptools

Suppose I've created a whl package containing two classes:

```
my_pkg
  __init__.py
  my_file1.py # declares MyClass1
  my_file2.py # declares MyClass2
```

Now to use one of the classes, someone would have to write:

```py
from my_pkg.my_file1 import MyClass1
```

Coming from a C# background, I consider it irrelevant what files my classes are defined in. I'd like to be able to write:

```py
from my_pkg import MyClass1

mc1 = MyClass1()
```

How can I achieve this? Declare all my classes in `__init__.py`?

Comment: Adding `from .my_file1 import MyClass1` to your `__init__.py` should do it.

Comment: @Kemp: Exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks!